# How to divide int64_t to two int32_t and send it over the network?

Tags: c, unix, udp, posix, int64

I want to send two `int64_t` over UDP. To do this I store them in a four-element array, where:

- [0] - lower 32 its of the first `int64_t`
- [1] - higher 32 bits of the first `int64_t`
- [2] - lower 32 bits of the second `int64_t`
- [3] - higher 32 bits if the second `int64_t`

My code for sending:

```
int64_t from, to;

/* some logic here */

data[0] = htonl((int32_t) from);
data[1] = htonl((int32_t) (from >> 32));
data[2] = htonl((int32_t) to);
data[3] = htonl((int32_t) (to >> 32));

/* sending via UDP here */
```

My code for combining `int32_t` back to `int64_t` after receiving `data` via UDP:

```
int64_t from, to;
from = (int64_t) ntohl(data[1]);
from = (from << 32);
from = from | (int64_t) ntohl(data[0]);
to = (int64_t) ntohl(data[3]);
to = (to << 32);
to = from | (int64_t) ntohl(data[2]);

printf("received from = %" PRId64 "\n", from);
printf("received to = %" PRId64 "\n", to);
```

The first number (`from`) is always correct. However, what I get from the second `printf` is incorrect. What's more, it seems to be dependent on the first number. Example:

Sending:

- `from` = 125,
- `to` = 20.

Received:

- `from` = 125,
- `to` = 125.

Sending:

- `from` = 1252,
- `to` = 20.

Received:

- `from` = 1252,
- `to` = 1268.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the problem of conversion or sending over the network?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it ok to do this kind of stuff with signed numbers rather than unsigned ones? E.g. `(int32_t) from` is a signed overflow, right? Isn't that unspecified behavior or so? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow "In the C programming language, signed integer overflow causes undefined behavior"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in your receiver code:

```
to = from | (int64_t) ntohl(data[2]);
```

should be

```
to = to | (int64_t) ntohl(data[2]);
```

Comment: +1. This is why repeating code (or copy-pasting) it is bad and you should put that kind of stuff into methods/macros – as soon as the brain turns off, your fingers start typing garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're sending the 64-bit values backwards. `htonl()` makes sure the int32s are sent in the correct order, but [RFC 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700) defines that the most significant octet of the field is to be transmitted first:

> When a multi-octet quantity is transmitted the most significant octet is
> transmitted first.